# password authentication failed in postgresql with django

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm trying to learn web development with Django and I was following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) to do so.

Everything works fine until I run the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get this error message:

```
password authentication failed for user "myprojectuser"
```

I have checked and rechecked many times and the password is correct in the **`settings.py`** file.

Below is the content of the file *(settings.py)*:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'myproject',
    'USER': 'myprojectuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I am using ***postgreSQL 9.5***, ***python 2.7***, and ***Django 1.10***.

Comment: What happens if you use psql to connect to the database as that user?

Comment: It works fine when I do that.

Comment: I usually just set the database by specifying the complete URL: `DATABASE = {'default': 'postgres://myprojectuser:password@127.0.0.1:5432/myproject'}`. You can give that a try and see if that makes a difference. Silly question -- you are specifying the actual password?

Answer (score 0):

From your guide:

"
By default, Postgres uses an authentication scheme called "peer authentication" for local connections. Basically, this means that if the user's operating system username matches a valid Postgres username, that user can login with no further authentication.
"

so I am guessing that if you will create a user for your DB with the same name as your OS local username it might work :)

Comment: I thought that was the problem but sadly it didn't work either. :( I changed the authentication to md5 but unfortunately that's not working either.

Answer (score 0):

In case the "DATABASES" setting you showed are not the one you actually use - check if the "NAME" and the "USER" are in lowercase